# Why do we not talk about coherent sheaves on nonoetherian schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In $II.5$ Hartshorne makes the following statement:

*Although we have defined quasi-coherence and coherence on an arbitrary scheme we will talk about coherence when the scheme is Noetherian. This is because the notion of coherence is not well-behaved on a nonoetherian scheme.*

Can someone expound on this statement?

For example, it seems still obvious to me that the structure sheaf of a nonoetherian affine scheme, $\operatorname{Spec} A$, would be coherent. How would $A$ not being Noetherian cause problems?

Comment: The category of finite type quasi-coherent sheaves on a scheme is not closed under taking kernels, for example. The notion of coherence sheaves is different from finite type quasi-coherent sheaves on a general scheme. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_sheaf, so the structure sheaf is not coherent on $Spec A$ if $A$ itself is not a coherent ring.

Comment: Here are some examples of things that go wrong. First off, a lot of problems are already apperent over the spectrum of a Noetherian ring. Over Noetherian rings, the notions of finitely generated and finitely presented coincide, but over non-Noetherian rings they don't. There can be unfortunate things, like having a subsheaf, or quotient sheaf of a coherent sheaf being only quasi-coherent, which makes the category really bad. It also makes things we want to be coherent not, like the structure sheaf of a closed subscheme.